# Multiple inline divs that exceed the container width

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to keep multiple divs inline if their width exceeds container width.If the width of all divs is about 1000 px and the container's width is 500 , i want the divs to be overlapped by container , and a horizontal scroll bar to show up.

```css
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
#container>div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
  <div class="fourth"></div>
  <br style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

Fiddle: [Click](http://jsfiddle.net/WGCyu/1322/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use float, use inline block with container set to nowrap for white space, and then add `overflow: auto;` to the container to trigger the scrollbar as needed.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WGCyu/1328/)**

```
#container{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
#container>div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @PetruLebada Glad to hear that, you might be seeing some extra whitespace between the inline blocks, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Add some CSS

```
#container {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 500px;
}

#container > div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 30%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WGCyu/1325/

Answer (score 1):

As Pangloss says, don't use **float**, but display them inline. And use **overflow-x:scroll**

```css
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x:scroll
}
#container>div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
  <div class="fourth"></div>
  <br style="clear: both;">
</div>
```